# How to change the set value everytime the "while" loop resets

Tags: python

So I'm making a very simple battle mechanic in python where the player will be able to attack, defend
or inspect the enemy :

```
print("------Welcome To The Game------")
player_hp=5
player_attack=3
enemy_hp=10
enemy_attack=2

while player_hp !=0 and enemy_hp !=0:
      Choice=input("""What will you do: 
      A.Attack
      B.Defend
      C.Inspect
      (A/B/C): """)
      if Choice=="A":
         enemy_hp-player_attack
         print("You dealt",str(player_attack), " damage"
      if Choice=="B":
         dice_roll=set(("1","2","3","4","5"))
         dice_list=list(dice_roll)
         value=dice_list[0]
         if value =="1":
            player_hp-1
         elif value=="2":
            player_hp-2
         elif value=="3":
            player_hp-3
         elif value=="4":
            player_hp-4
         elif value=="5":
            player_hp-5
       if Choice=="C":
          print("""Enemy hp is,enemy_hp
                Enemy attack is ,enemy_attack""")
else:
   if player_hp ==0:
      print("you lost")
   if enemy_hp==0:
      print("you won")
```

Problem that I'm having is that the **value** number doesn't reset after the loop finishes , if let's say the value first was 2 damage it will remain 2 everytime you press B until your hp finishes , so how can I make it that everytime you press the **defend** option the value is different?

Comment: `value=dice_list[0]` will always be "1" if the choice is "B". What do you mean "reset"?

Comment: you could define `dice_list` at start - you don't have to define it again and again inside `while`-loop. And you don't have to use `set()` for this bu directly `dice_list = ["1","2","3","4","5"]`

Answer (score 2):

You should not rely on sets to provide random arrangements of values.
In this case you should use `random.randint` function.
Example:

```
import random

if Choice== "B":
    player_hp -= random.randint(1, 5)
```

Also as Shayan pointed out you are not modifying `player_hp` by doing `player_hp - ...` you should use `player_hp -= ...` instead.

Comment: Notice that the OP wants a value from 1 to 5, and that in your code also 6 would be included. Anyway this is a working answer, +1

Comment: You are right, I got confused by the `dice_roll` variable name hah. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is where you don't change the `enemy_hp` and `player_hp`! For example, when player choose to attack, then `enemy_hp` should decrease by `enemy_hp = enemy_hp-player_attack`.
This is also necessary for `player_hp` too!

So I think the code will be:

```
import random
print("------Welcome To The Game------")
player_hp=5
player_attack=3
enemy_hp=10
enemy_attack=2

while player_hp >0 and enemy_hp >0:
    Choice=input("""What will you do: 
    A.Attack
    B.Defend
    C.Inspect
    (A/B/C): """)
    if Choice=="A":
        enemy_hp =enemy_hp-player_attack
        print("You dealt",str(player_attack), f" damage and enemy hp is {enemy_hp}")
        
    elif Choice=="B":
        dice_roll=set(("1","2","3","4","5"))
        dice_list=list(dice_roll)
        value= random.choice(dice_list)
        if value =="1":
            player_hp= player_hp-1
        elif value=="2":
            player_hp=player_hp-2
        elif value=="3":
            player_hp=player_hp-3
        elif value=="4":
            player_hp=player_hp-4
        elif value=="5":
            player_hp=player_hp-5
        

    elif Choice=="C":
        print(f"Enemy hp is,{enemy_hp} Enemy attack is {value}")

if enemy_hp<=0:
    print("you won")

elif player_hp <=0:
    print("you lost")
```

**Important notes:**

1. You should consider that `player_hp` and `enemy_hp` should be checked continuously! so they should be written in the `while` loop, not the outside!
2. Another Important point is based on your code this can be concluded that the damage of the enemy is randomly chosen between numbers from 1 to 5! Because you decreased `player_hp` by these numbers! so `enemy_attack` is useless in this code!
3. Conditions for `while` loop should be changed to `player_hp >0 and enemy_hp >0`! `player_hp >0` means that player is alive. this is meaningful for `enemy_hp >0` as well!
4. as mwo said:

   > You should not rely on sets to provide random arrangements of values.

   So we can use the `random` library to randomly choose a value from `dice_list` with `random.choice(dice_list)`.
5. It's not a good idea to define `dice_roll` inside the `while` loop. in this way, you are defining `dice_roll` again and again where this isn't necessary at all! so it's recommended to define it before the `while` loop. in this case, you can define `dice_list` like this before `while` loop: `dice_list=["1","2","3","4","5"]`
6. Also you don't need to define many conditions for subtracting the damage from `player_hp`! `player_hp= player_hp-value` would be enough and you don't need to `if/elif` statements there.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I make it that everytime you press the defend option the value is different

You should look at using the `random` module

Ignoring the game logic, here's a simple example

```
import random

dice_values = list(range(1, 7))  # example for six-sided die

alive = True
while alive:
  value = random.choice(dice_values)
  print(f'you picked {value}')
```

Comment: I would use random.randint() over random.choice(list(range())), but yes, this is a valid option. +1

Comment: Not all dice have sequential numbers. You mean randint as a list index?

Comment: I simply don't get the difference between picking a random number between 1 and 6 and picking a random element from a range that goes from 1 to 6...

Comment: Like I said, not all dice have numbers. Or this could be a list of strings like `['attack', 'defend', 'skip']`.

Comment: Now I get what you mean... I didn't understand this because the OP's code was showing a multiple if/elif statement that associated "1" with 1 and so on, so I thought they only needed numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
     dice_roll=set(("1","2","3","4","5"))
     dice_list=list(dice_roll)
     value=dice_list[0]
     ...
        player_hp-4
     elif value=="5":
        player_hp-5
```

This code you created is a way of generating a random number, but there are better ways of doing this.

---

Using the module `random`, you can access the function `random.randint`, which generates a random `int` between two given numbers:

```
>>> random.randint(0, 10) # It includes both the extremes
4
```

So a better idea would be:

```
player_hp-=random.randint(1, 5)
```

---

You should also be aware that:

```
player_hp-5
```

doesn't reduce `player_hp` by `5`, because it's not an assignation, you can do it in one of this ways:

```
player_hp-=5
# ...or...
player_hp = player_hp-5
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others have already recommended, I would also use the random function for an randomly chosen int between 1 and 5. If I understood your program correctly, in choice B you want the chosen value to be the players defence and the attack from the opponent to be subtracted from it. This would be my suggested solution

```
import random
print("------Welcome To The Game------")
min = 1
max = 5
player_hp=5
player_attack=3
enemy_hp=10
enemy_attack=

while player_hp>0 and enemy_hp>0:
      Choice=input("""What will you do: 
      A.Attack
      B.Defend
      C.Inspect
      (A/B/C): """)
      if Choice=="A":
         enemy_hp = enemy_hp-player_attack
         print("You dealt",str(player_attack), "damage")
      elif Choice=="B":
         defence = random.randint(min,max)
         print("value of defense is",defence)
         damage = defence - enemy_attack
         if damage < 0:
            print("value of damage is",damage)
            player_hp = player_hp - (-damage)
         else: 
            print("there was no damage")
      elif Choice=="C":
         print("player hp is",player_hp)
         print("enemy hp is",enemy_hp)
else:
    if player_hp<=0:
        print("you lost")
    if enemy_hp<=0:
        print("you won")
```